# Trigger action when a number of records is reached in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, heroku

I have an app that stores records of an object called kpivalue. Each user can store a limited number of records, several thousands of them. So I need to be aware of when the users reach the limit.

I know I can count them and for example check the status using an after_create callback of active_record.

But is there a more optimized way of doing it? So I don't need to count after create? Something that would trigger an action when the limit is reached.

I'm using Heroku with postgresql and Rails 3.2.8

Answer (score 0):

You *can* trigger an action when the number of items in an association reaches a certain number, but do you really need to worry unless they've tried to add one more than the limit?

I would suggest instead that you approach this by stopping the user from exceeding the limit, rather than responding to them reaching the limit.

You can validate the number of associated items like so:

```
class User
  has_many :kpivalues
  validate :kpivalues_within_limit

private

  def kpilimit
    5000
  end

  def kpivalues_within_limit
    return if self.kpivalues.blank?
    errors.add("You may only have #{kpilimit.to_s} kpivalues") if self.kpivalues.count > kpilimit
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment Matt. I need to worry, more records mean a higher plan for the user to subscribe. Yeah a validate on create would be a possibility. Would that be any different than a filter on before or after create, performance wise? I would like to have the most automatic way of doing it, maybe direct DB triggers, but not sure if they are possible on Heroku dbs.

Answer (score 0):

`after_create` is the Rails way to deal with this. If you need more efficiency, you can use SQL triggers to raise an SQL exception if the limit is reached, which would probably be a bit faster than doing the check on the application level. This would also enforce the check in a stronger way, since you wouldn't be able to break the limit outside the ActiveRecord model, not even with a direct SQL query outside the rails app. This being said, `after_create` is probably what you need and is by far simpler to use than SQL triggers.